# Inner product defined with matrix

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, inner-products

Define a function such that $<X,Y> = \overline{Y^t}AX$ where $A$ is a real $3\times 3$ matrix and
$X,Y$ are $3\times1$ complex matrices. Since,

> $\overline{<X,Y>}=\overline{\overline{Y^t}AX}=Y^tA\overline{X}$

$Y^tA\overline{X}$ doesn't have to equal $<Y,X>=\overline{X^t}AY$ so this is not inner product. Is it a true way to show this?

Comment: $y^t A \bar{x}$ is a $1\times 1$ matrix and so equal to its transpose.

Comment: whether this is an inner product or not depends on whether $A$ is positive definite